# Copy large files into HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, ioexception

I'm trying to copy a large file (32 GB) into HDFS. I never had any troubles copying files in HDFS but these were all smaller. I'm using `hadoop fs -put <myfile> <myhdfsfile>` and up to 13,7 GB everything goes well but then I get this exception:

```
hadoop fs -put * /data/unprocessed/
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSError: java.io.IOException: Input/output error
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileInputStream.read(RawLocalFileSystem.java:150)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:149)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.readFully(FSInputChecker.java:384)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.readChunk(ChecksumFileSystem.java:217)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.readChecksumChunk(FSInputChecker.java:237)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.read1(FSInputChecker.java:189)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.read(FSInputChecker.java:158)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:74)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:47)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:230)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:191)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1183)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.copyFromLocal(FsShell.java:130)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.run(FsShell.java:1762)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.main(FsShell.java:1895)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Input/output error
        at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:242)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$TrackingFileInputStream.read(RawLocalFileSystem.java:91)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileInputStream.read(RawLocalFileSystem.java:144)
        ... 20 more
```

When I check the log files (on my NameNode and DataNodes) I see that the lease on the file is removed but there's no reason specified. According to the log files everything went well. Here are the last lines of my NameNode log:

```
2013-01-28 09:43:34,176 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: BLOCK* NameSystem.allocateBlock: /data/unprocessed/AMR_EXPORT.csv. blk_-4784588526865920213_1001
2013-01-28 09:44:16,459 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: BLOCK* NameSystem.addStoredBlock: blockMap updated: 10.1.6.114:50010 is added to blk_-4784588526865920213_1001 size 30466048
2013-01-28 09:44:16,466 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: Removing lease on  file /data/unprocessed/AMR_EXPORT.csv from client DFSClient_1738322483
2013-01-28 09:44:16,472 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* NameSystem.completeFile: file /data/unprocessed/AMR_EXPORT.csv is closed by DFSClient_1738322483
2013-01-28 09:44:16,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Number of transactions: 168 Total time for transactions(ms): 26Number of transactions batched in Syncs: 0 Number of syncs: 0 SyncTimes(ms): 0
```

Does anyone have a clue on this? I've checked `core-default.xml` and `hdfs-default.xml` for properties I could overwrite that would extend the lease or so but couldn't find one.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

- If you have multiple files to copy then use multiple -put sessions
- If there is only one large file then use compression before copy OR you can split the large file into small ones then copy

Comment: I do have one very large file. I'm trying your suggestions. At the moment I'm compressing using BZip so my file will still be splittable after it has been copied to HDFS. It's a shame it takes such a long time though. I also tried splitting it using `split -b 4096m` and this works. The only problem with this latter approach is that at the moment I'm testing Hadoop on 3 old laptops which have a 60GB hard drive so there is no space to split a 32GB file. On the other hand, Hadoop should be able to handle files of this size, no?

Comment: For that matter, I've tried copying 1 TB file using -copyFromLocal and it worked for me without any issue but I have 300+ node cluster here :-)

Comment: In a desperate attempt, I just tried it once more and for some strange reason I managed to copy the file. I have no idea what caused the error before but I tried it nearly 10 times using both `-copyFromLocal` and `-put`. The file is in HDFS now but I'm quite sure that if I'll try it again, it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to be an issue reading the local file than a problem with the hdfs client. The stack trace shows a problem reading the local file that has bubbled all the way up. The lease is dropped because the client has dropped the connection due to the IOException while reading the file.

Comment: But why would there be a problem reading the file after 13 GB has been copied already? What would you recommend?

Comment: Then possibly there is some issue with the integrity of the file on your local disk that occurs on the 13 GB offset. I suggest running an arbitrary operation on the file that scans all the contents and see if it succeeds reading the whole file. For example, try md5sum.

Comment: I don't think there's something wrong with my file. I just managed to copy it to HDFS. After the tenth attempt for some reason it did suddenly work. I agree with you that it's most likely a client side problem but I'd just really like to know what could have caused it because I think chances are big I'll run into it again.